# How to make a Native Node.js module for one platform only?

Tags: c++, node.js, windows, native

I have a multiplatform Node.js application, and on one platform (windows) I need a Native Node.js module. It isn't needed on other platforms and fails to compile.

How can I go about making sure the module only gets the native element installed on Windows? Currently I have it as an optional dependency, but on other platforms people doing `npm install` will see an error.

Ideally on all other platforms the module would get installed without error, but just without the native bit. Obviously I could just `ifdef` all of the C file, but then it'd still fail to install for Mac users without XCode.

If it helps, this is my module - I tried to make it windows-only with `OS==win` in `binding.gyp` but there are still problems: https://github.com/espruino/winnus

thanks!